# R read file with header columns into data.frame

Tags: r, header, dataframe, multiple-columns

I read a text file as follows:

```
a <- read.table("~/Desktop/seed_ant.dat", header = TRUE, skip = 3)
```

but the columns are not properly identified:

```
> a
1 Colony,Distance,Mass,Headwidth,Headwidth (mm),Worker class
2                             28,0,62.000,39.000,1.642,39-40
3                             28,0,53.000,39.000,1.642,39-40
4                             28,0,51.000,38.000,1.600,37-38
```

How do I recognize the columns now shown in line 1?

Comment: Can you explain how you read that data into R?  Usually, if you're dealing with standard file formats, you can just use `read.table(..., header=TRUE)` and the headers will be put as column names automatically.  This data format looks somewhat odd for an R data frame.

Comment: You will also want `sep = ','` or call `read.csv(... header=TRUE)`.

Comment: I did like this @lakinsm a <- read.table("~/Desktop/seed_ant.dat", header = TRUE, skip = 3)

Comment: If you're still having trouble, edit your question and add the first few lines from your raw data file and that should help.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 a <- read.csv("~/Desktop/seed_ant.dat", header = TRUE, skip = 3)
```

or

```
 a <- read.table("~/Desktop/seed_ant.dat", header = TRUE, skip = 3, sep = ",")
```

Based on the output of the `data.frame` `a`, you may need to use `skip = 4` to indicate the columns correctly. It's hard to say exactly without the first few lines of your input file.